# Postgres select only items which are conform to a given set

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have a table like:

```
ref_id  value
-------------
 1     test1 
 2     test1
 1     test2
 1     test3
```

Now I want to select only those ref_id's, if the value belongs to ref_id matches ALL values of a given set. For example, if the given set looks like ('test1','test2') the result should be:

```
ref_id  
-------
   1
```

If the set is ('test1') the result should be:

```
ref_id
------
  1
  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays for that:

```
with t(ref_id,value) as (values
  (1,'test1'),(2,'test1'),(1,'test2'),(1,'test3'))
select ref_id, value from
  (select ref_id, array_agg(distinct value) as value from t group by ref_id) as s
where
  value @> array['test1']
  --value @> array['test1','test2']
```

Or, simpler:

```
select ref_id from t
group by ref_id
having array_agg(value) @> array['test1']
```

Read more about [`@>` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) and [`array_agg` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `group by` and `having`.  You don't specify what the "set" looks like, but here is an example:

```
select ref_id
from t
where value in ('test1', 'test2')
group by ref_id
having count(*) = 2; <-- size of set
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest our table named **ref** and set for matching is present in **matchset** table.

If pair (ref_id:value) is unique within **ref** table try following:

```
select ref_id
from ref r
join matchset s
on s.value = r.value
group by ref_id
having count(*)=(select count(*) from matchset)
```

If same pair (ref_id:value) may occur more than once we need to filter out duplicates

```
with r as(
select distinct ref_id, value
from ref
)
select ref_id
from r
join matchset s
on s.value = r.value
group by ref_id
having count(*)=(select count(*) from matchset)
```